# Facing challenge to invoke cloud Function from cloud task using oidcToken

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-iam, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-tasks

I am facing challenge to invoke cloud Function from cloud task using **oidcToken**.

Here are details of my IAM & Code:

```
const { CloudTasksClient } = require('@google-cloud/tasks');
const client = new CloudTasksClient();

//See https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/tutorial-gcf
module.exports = async (payload, scheduleTimeInSec) => {
  const project = process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_PROJECTID;
  const queue = process.env.QUEUE_NAME;
  const location = process.env.QUEUE_LOCATION;
  const callBackUrl = https://asia-south2-trial-288318.cloudfunctions.net/cloud-function-node-expres/;

  // Construct the fully qualified queue name.
  const parent = client.queuePath(project, location, queue);

  const body = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString('base64');

  const task = {
    httpRequest: {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      url: callBackUrl,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body
    },
    scheduleTime: {
      seconds: scheduleTimeInSec,
    }
  };

  if (process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL) {
    task.httpRequest.oidcToken = {
      serviceAccountEmail: process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL
    }
  }

  const request = {
    parent: parent,
    task: task,
  };

  // Send create task request.
  try {
    let [responses] = await client.createTask(request);

    return ({ sts: true, taskName: responses.name, msg: "Email Schedule Task Created" })
  }
  catch (e) {
    return ({ sts: true, err: true, errInfo: e, msg: "Unable to Schedule Task. Internal Error." })
  }
}
```

The process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL has **Cloud Functions Invoker** role and the Cloud Function has **allAuthenticatedUsers** member with role **Cloud Functions Invoker** as per the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/tutorial-gcf).

But still I am seeing the 401 resposnse recevied by Cloud Task and Cloud Function is not getting called(See below image):

[image]

Any comment on this, whats going wrong here

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be related that you have created the function in Firebase (guessing from the url). Seems the "Cloud Functions Invoker" is not enough for Firebase functions. I have replicated similar behavior on HelloWorld function from Firebase.  The error is differnet (403) but I hope it will help you to troubleshoot the same way.

After creation helloWorld in Firebase I tested it with `glcoud` command in following steps:

1. Create service acount with role "Cloud Functions Invoker" or use exiting one
2. Download key for the account in JSON.
3. Change `gcloud` to act as service account:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account <service-account@email> --key-file=<key-form-step-2.json>
```

4. `gcloud functions call helloWorld`

As the result of last action I got this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.call) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Forbidden], message=[Permission 'cloudfunctions.functions.call' denied on resource 'projects/functions-asia-test-vitooh/locations/us-central1/functions/helloWorld' (or reso
urce may not exist).]
```

So I created custom role in IAM: **Cloud Functions Invoker + Firebase** adding permission from the error massage `cloudfunctions.functions.call`.

The function started to work with the same `gcloud functions call`:

```
executionId: 3fgndpolu981
result: Hello from Firebase!
```

I think it will work as well. You can try add the same permission. If it wont work, try the same testing.

References:

- [gcloud auth command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account)
- [create custom role in Cloud IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles)
- [gcloud function call](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/call)

Comment: @vitooth, Thank you so much for taking your valuable time and creating examples, I will try and let you know. Sorry for the late response, I was busy with some other work.